# Maven Error:Artifact is not a dependency of the project

Tags: java, maven

```
   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-
    plugin:2.6:generate-application-xml (default-generate-application-xml) 
    on project itaras-ear: Artifact[war:org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-
    plugin] is not a dependency of the project.
```

First I built a WAR file for my application. Now I am in the process of building my EAR file which is supposed to have WAR as dependency.

I have run ITARAS-EAR module with m2e plugin when I got the above mentioned error message.

module WAR's pom.xml is below.

```
  <parent>
   <groupId>itaras</groupId>
   <artifactId>itaras</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
<groupId>itaras-war</groupId>
 <artifactId>itaras-war</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>            
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
       <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>        
      </configuration>
     </plugin>
     </plugins>
       </build>
    </project>
```

Module EAR's pom.xml is here.

```
  <parent>
  <groupId>itaras</groupId>
  <artifactId>itaras</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
 <artifactId>itaras-ear</artifactId>
 <packaging>ear</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>itaras-war</groupId>
        <artifactId>itaras-war</artifactId>

        <type>war</type>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

   </dependencies>
     <build>
     <plugins>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
              <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
            <applicationXML>src/main/application/META-
        INF/application.xml</applicationXML>
         </configuration>
    </plugin>
     </plugins>
    </build>
    <groupId>itaras-ear</groupId>
     </project>
```

Thanks in advance. Do Correct me if I had gone fundamentally wrong :)

Comment: PS: I am trying to do stuffs without knowing what it does exactly. Just trying things by getting them through searching

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your war project has 2 groupIds

```
<parent>
   <groupId>itaras</groupId>
   <artifactId>itaras</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
*** <groupId>itaras-war</groupId> ****
<artifactId>itaras-war</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Remove the groupId and allow it to pick it's groupId from the parent.  Only specify the artifactId, version and groupId from the parent.

Then your dependency to the war in your ear project is:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>itaras</groupId>
      <artifactId>itaras-war</artifactId>
      <type>war</type>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. But still the error persists.. Is there anythinh else I have got to do?